# Django form deletes row data when using instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a multiple page form that I'm managing. When I update the record it deletes all the previously captured data.

Model

```
class User(models.Model):
    first = models.CharField(max_length=45L, db_column='First', blank=True)
    last = models.CharField(max_length=45L, db_column='Last', blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=60L, db_column='Email', blank=True)
```

Form

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

Form 1 captures the email:

```
def form_one(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.POST
        uf = UserForm(request.POST)
        if uf.is_valid():
            user = uf.save()
            request.session['id'] = user.id
```

Prints:

```
<QueryDict: {u'email': [u'test@test.com']}>
```

Database shows record with email

Form 2 captures the user name:

```
def form_one(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.POST
        current_user = User.objects.get(id = request.session['id'])
        uf = UserForm(request.POST, instance = current_user)
        if uf.is_valid():
            uf.save()
```

Prints:

```
<QueryDict: {u'last': [u'Smith'], u'first': [u'Joe']}>
```

Database shows same record, deleted email, but first & last name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your email field has `blank=True`, so the empty string '' is a valid value. This means the email is wiped if you do not provide a value for it in the post data.

If you don't want to include the email field in your second form, then exclude it.

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta
        model = User
        exclude = ('email',)
```

Comment: I understand now, but I'm using one form for the model. Is there another set of args I can use on the Model's field to allow blank, but not overwrite?

Comment: You can use a different form in each view. No, there is not an argument that 'allows blank but doesn't overwrite'.

Comment: What about merging Models? user = UserForm(request.POST).save(commit=False) current_user.merge(user) current_user.save()

Comment: There is no `merge` method. You would have to implement that yourself, which could be tricky.